# Remove UFW Block from kern.log and sys.log

Tags: logging, syslog, ufw

Using Nginx, Wordpress and Ubuntu 16.

I am constantly bombarded with these messages in `kern.log , syslog and ufw.log`

```
Nov 28 21:02:28 kernel: [246817.450026] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=122.3.133.77 DST=xx.xx LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=22334 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45750 DPT=23 WINDOW=5808 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Nov 28 21:02:31 kernel: [246820.443191] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=122.3.133.77 DST=xx.xx LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=22335 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45750 DPT=23 WINDOW=5808 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Nov 28 21:02:33 kernel: [246822.448520] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=195.154.181.110 DST=xx.xx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=6401 PROTO=TCP SPT=52845 DPT=8709 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Nov 28 21:02:37 kernel: [246826.438721] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=122.3.133.77 DST=xx.xx LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=22336 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45750 DPT=23 WINDOW=5808 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Nov 28 21:03:26 kernel: [246875.605969] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=89.163.146.88 DST=xx.xx LEN=444 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=45590 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5149 DPT=5060 LEN=424 
Nov 28 21:03:41 kernel: [246890.099144] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=82.81.171.85 DST=xx.xx LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=19683 PROTO=TCP SPT=63561 DPT=2323 WINDOW=58193 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Nov 28 21:03:46 kernel: [246895.517766] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=94.102.49.174 DST=xx.xx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=249 ID=2066 PROTO=TCP SPT=51511 DPT=8000 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Nov 28 21:03:49 kernel: [246898.714239] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=61.240.144.65 DST=xx.xx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=236 ID=31567 PROTO=TCP SPT=46807 DPT=8009 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Nov 28 21:04:14 kernel: [246923.959948] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=163.172.91.185 DST=xx.xx LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=47175 DPT=22 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Nov 28 21:04:31 kernel: [246940.250298] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx.xx SRC=78.168.185.115 DST=xx.xx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=62125 PROTO=TCP SPT=52008 DPT=7547 WINDOW=13555 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

1. Since these are already logged in ufw.log how can i stop them from appearing at kern.log and syslog ?
2. Is there something I must do to prevent these attacks or is this normal for a server to experience?

Answer (score 19):

[UFW](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) configuration option only toggles logging on/off (and alternatively specifies custom logging level):

> `logging on|off|LEVEL`
>
> toggle logging. Logged packets use the `LOG_KERN` syslog facility.
>      Systems   configured   for  `rsyslog`  support  may  also  log  to
>      `/var/log/ufw.log`. Specifying a `LEVEL` turns logging  on  for  the
>      specified  `LEVEL`.  The  default log level is `low`.

If you are using standard Ubuntu installation, you have `rsyslogd` extension, which can be (and by default is) [configured](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html) to generate these separated log files.

In Ubuntu 16.04, UFW logging configuration should be in `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf`:

```
# Log kernel generated UFW log messages to file
:msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log

# Uncomment the following to stop logging anything that matches the last rule.
# Doing this will stop logging kernel generated UFW log messages to the file
# normally containing kern.* messages (eg, /var/log/kern.log)
#& ~
```

As the comment describes, you should just uncomment the last line. If there isn't one, just add `& ~`.

Contrariwise, commenting out the other configuration line causes logging only to `syslog` / `kern.log`.

---

**2:** Using a firewall to block attacks, as you already do, is the correct way to handle the situation.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me!  Just a quick note that you need to restart rsyslog for it to take effect: sudo service rsyslog restart

Comment: My copy of 20-ufw.conf has a "& stop" directive instead. Any significant difference? It doesn't log to syslog or kern.log anymore with that.

Comment: @icelava must be newer version, I have the same on Ubuntu 20.04. It has the same effect.

Comment: another way to get rid of annoying UFW-BLOCK lines in your log is to whitelist which IPs you want to allow connection, and add a last rule "denying from any to any", then there will be no log entry, as suggested here https://askubuntu.com/a/1383632/1179344.